# ERROR: password authentication failed for user "postgres" ao rodar ```npx sequelize db:create```

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize-js, docker

Estou obtendo esse erro quando tento criar um banco através do comando `npx sequelize db:create` no server postgresql rodando em um container docker.

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.5'
volumes: 
  data: 

services: 
  database:
    container_name: container_name
    image: postgres:12
    ports: 
      - 15432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*****
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - type: tmpfs
        target: /dev/shm
```

Configurações do sequelize:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
    dialect: 'postgres', 
    host: "localhost", 
    database: process.env.DB_NAME, 
    username: process.env.DB_UNAME, //postgres
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD, // a mesma senha que setei nas variáveis de ambiente no docker-compose 
    define: {
        timestamps: true, 
        underscored: true
    }
};
```

Não é erro de configuração, estou esquecendo de algum passo de conexão com o container, porque consigo conectar ao server postgres rodando na minha máquina e funciona normalmente com essas configurações

Comment: Pelo que eu vi está faltando setar a porta visto que não esta usando a portão padrão é necessário declarar

Comment: Desculpe ainda estou aprendendo, mas  como posso fazer isso? seto nas configurações do sequelize?

Comment: Pelo que eu vi na documentação basta inserir uma nova linha nesse arquivo de configuração do Sequelize. Algo assim: `port: 15432,`. Tem um exemplo de configuração que utiliza porta neste link da [documentação](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/)

Comment: Sim, de fato. Era isso mesmo.

Answer (score -2):

Encontrei a [resposta](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#:%7E:text=Sequelize%20will%20use%20the%20default,you%20can%20simply%20add%20it) na doc. do sequelize. Bastava apenas que eu setasse a porta nas configurações do arquivo. Dessa maneira:

```
module.exports = {
    dialect: 'postgres', 
    host: "localhost", 
    database: process.env.DB_NAME, 
    username: process.env.DB_UNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD, 
    port: "15432", // Aqui
    define: {
        timestamps: true, 
        underscored: true
    }
};
```

Comment: devia usar o valor que vem do .env também, não?

Comment: Sim, mas coloquei direto no código apenas para ilustrar